# migrating windows to linux java web app

Tags: java, linux, unix, jar

Good morning, I wish to migrate from a windows hosted web app into a linux hosted web app. My question is regarding some java jars.
It is my understanding that 3rd Party jars may not work on Linux environment. Need to check the compatibility and replace with appropriate jars but how would I know if the jars work on the environment, is there some tool I can use to check?

thanks so much in advance!

Comment: Its rare that a third party java jar would not be cross platform (selling point of java). How hard is it to simply deploy your app into linux and verify it works?

Comment: If you know that you have some "special" libraries (such as ones that would use JNI), you can check those, otherwise it won't be an issue.

Comment: In general it is not a problem. Some rare, _very_ specific libraries use native code, .dll's under Windows, .so under Linux. Even Windows authentication, Win Active Directory in general goes via the LDAP protocol, independently. Check for MS things like Excel and so on.

Comment: There should be not issue, just put it on linux, and see what happens, if no issue then ok, if issue, debug it, normally only jars that call 3rd native lib would have problems, but I think your jars is not of that type.

Answer (score 0):

As a general practice you should have an array of tests for your web application. I would deploy it and run the tests. If they are comprehensive enough and they pass it means that nothing you have thought of testing for is failing. In particular, it should test all your use cases.